# Select() + UDP resulting in too many open files

Tags: c++, sockets, select, network-programming

I currently have a select() statement configured to keep track of two UDP sockers. I send perhaps 10 - 20 messages a second at one general data socket, which is this interpreted as I expected.

However, once I hit around 1024 messages, I get the notice:

> talker: socket: Too many open files
>   talker: failed to bind socket

This is logical to me, since ulimit -n shows a max of 1024 open files for this user. However, why are there all of these open files? With UDP, there is no connection made, so I do not believe I need to be closing a socket each time (although perhaps I'm wrong).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are you creating the sockets?  wait I saw your comment about not needing to close the socket since it's UDP.  You still need to close it.  But you can reuse it in your select like you're doing.  I think it is the code you are using to send the messages that is causing the problem, not the select.

Comment: @SB I've added the code for the socket creation. You think it is the sending of the messages which is the issue? Hmm

Comment: @SB I checked my sending code --- I close the socket after relaying a message.

Comment: Which side errors out? Client or server?

Comment: Why is there more than one socket? I agree with the guys, it's probably socket creation bug.

Comment: @Nikolai -- this code simply allows a message to continuously be relayed. Once any of the relays reaches their max open file limit, this error occurs. The sending portion is what appears to be erroring out ("talker"). However, talker opens a port and then closes it every time.

Comment: @Pavel There is more then one socket because I need to be able to easily distinguish between route updates and route messages. Route updates are processed, route messages are relayed.

Comment: @SB At what point would I be closing the socket? Within the select statement and then reopening it again?

Comment: Show the code for the "talker", the problem is there.

Comment: @Nikolai, I've added the code for udpsender, which is in charge of sending out packets. This is the "talker" component.

Comment: Are you opening files in the "talker" to get data from, are you closing them?

Comment: @Nikolai: No, talker just takes a message and relays it. I've filled in the routehelper.routeit component. This allows you to see the entire path here, from start to finish. Don't worry about the routehelper.rccommand, that isn't being triggered.

Comment: And there it is. I've found it. Its within the systemIP() function I was using. It kept opening sockets to determine the systems IP, but never closing them. My apologizes to everyone. Thanks for everyone's help! crazyscot's suggestion of lsof and /proc/<pid>/fd helped me recognize where the sockets were coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case "Too many open files" really means you've hit the file descriptor limit; network sockets count towards this limit. Are you sure that there's nothing else - say in `routehelper` - that's creating further sockets?

What platform are you running on? If Linux, `lsof` or grobbling around in `/proc/<pid>/fd` - while it's running, before it hits the limit - might illustrate where all the fds are going.

Tip: Don't rely on `socket_udp_inboundALL` being numerically larger than `socket_udp_inboundRC` - it's better to explicitly compare their values at least once.

Comment: Thank you -- lsof pointed me into the right direction. Full explanation below.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux do an [`strace(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) on the client to check for the `socket(2)` and `open(2)` vs `close(2)` system calls (try `-e trace=socket,open,close` option). This is the easiest way to balance the file descriptor count at this point.

Comment: Thanks -- I was unaware of this option. lsof helped me this time, but perhaps strace will be help next time (+1).

Comment: Yes, that's a great one to keep in your toolbox, along with `lsof` and `tcpdump` :)