# "require_once(): Failed opening required" but file exists and is readable

Tags: php, node.js, redis, locking, pm2

Since some days I encounter a serious problem with one of my Cronjobs. Sometimes I get the following error (once or twice per hour):

> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'MailError.php' (include_path='.:/usr/www/users/web1/master/sys/classes:..') in [...]

The file that PHP fails to open changes every time. Furthermore the required file exists for sure and is readable. I tried to find any locked files with `lsof | grep .php` while the Cronjob is active  but there is no locked *.php file.

The `require_once` is called in my `spl_autoload_register` method:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className){
    $filePath = str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

    $includePaths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path());
    foreach($includePaths as $includePath){
        if(file_exists($includePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filePath)){
            require_once $filePath;
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Before the problem encountered for the first time I installed some new software on the server. Node.js, PM2 for process monitoring, a Node.js script that listens on an UDP socket and Redis as a search result cache. I turned off all these components and now it looks like the Cronjob is running without any error again. Later I turned on the components one after another to check which one causes the error but it looks like it only occures if every component is turned on.

I have no clue what the core of that problem is so I hope I can find someone who had the same or a similar problem.

Some useful information about my system:

- Managed server with Debian 9 installed
- Node.js and Redis installed with Linuxbrew
- PHP 7.3.11-cli
- no anti-virus software in use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found out in this thread [Select() + UDP resulting in too many open files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136038/select-udp-resulting-in-too-many-open-files) this error is the result of a transgession of the open file limit.

In my case a PHP script uses an UDP socket with `socket_create()` and `socken_sendto()` and closes it with `socket_close()`. The closing may fail and the socket remains open. At some point the open file limit is exeeded and PHP can't include any further files.